# Laravel drop Unique Column

Tags: laravel, indexing, eloquent, unique

[image]

How can I drop unique of mail. `$table->dropUnique('customers_mail_unique');`is not work.

Anybody helps me solving this problem!
Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

First of all You don't have to create 3 questions with the same question.

Secondly, You can see, your `mail` key name is `100`, so `$table->dropUnique('100');` should work.

Comment: Sorry! I am in hurry! Sorry about it. Thank you for telling me

Comment: Futhermore, I can drop as you said. so sad!